# OpenSSL "hangs" after Client Hello - after renewing LetsEncrypt certificate

Tags: apache-2.4, openssl

I am running a Linux CentOS 7.6 based Apache on a virtual linux machine. I use LetsEncrypt certificates for HTTPS. This worked fine for half a year now.
Lately I had to renew certificates again. This also went smooth.

I can still connect via HTTPS and view web pages. But as soon as I start a download via HTTPS (does not depend on client), the downloads stalls after some megabytes. From this moment on, I cannot make any SSL based connection, since the TLS handshake fails - the Client Hello is not answered anymore, neither via HTTPS, nor via SSH. Also the Apache is completely unresponsive, even on HTTP.

I tried different ports and downloads from different networks to rule out eventually existing network proxies. I even triggered the problem, when downloading from localhost.

I traced via wireshark outgoing packets on the network interface and I can confirm, that the server hello is not being sent.

If I stop the client from downloading via HTTPS, it takes a few minutes and then the Server Hello packet from the TLS handshake is sent!!

So from my perspective, the TLS-secured connection with the new certificate blocks after having encrypted a low amount of megabytes en bloc. It seems to come alive some minutes afterwards. 
I have absolutely no idea, what to do now and I don't find any hints in the kernel or Apache logs that would give me a clue.

Do yo have any ideas?

**Update**:

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
  Include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-apache.conf
  Include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-apache.conf
  SSLCertificateFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/mydomain/cert.pem
  SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/mydomain/privkey.pem
  SSLCertificateChainFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/mydomain/chain.pem
</VirtualHost>
```

*options-ssl-apache.conf*

```
SSLEngine on
SSLProtocol             all -SSLv2 -SSLv3
SSLCipherSuite          ECDHE-ECDSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305:ECDHE-RSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:DHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA:DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA:DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA:ECDHE-ECDSA-DES-CBC3-SHA:ECDHE-RSA-DES-CBC3-SHA:EDH-RSA-DES-CBC3-SHA:AES128-GCM-SHA256:AES256-GCM-SHA384:AES128-SHA256:AES256-SHA256:AES128-SHA:AES256-SHA:DES-CBC3-SHA:!DSS
SSLHonorCipherOrder     on

SSLOptions +StrictRequire
```

Comment: If you post the relevant parts of apache configuration it might add some technical info to thequestion.

Comment: I did. But since they did not change that config since it was originally working, I did not think this is relevant. But of course, I may be wrong.
As I said, TLS is working perfectly - for small files. It only hangs on large files.